# When merging conflicts in the smerge mode, how to select "mine" for all conflicts in the file?

Tags: magit, git, smerge

When merging conflicts In smerge mode, how to select "mine" for all conflicts? At the moment I only know how to do it **one by one** with `smerge-use-lower` or `C-c ^ l`.

Update: a possible solution using Magit?

I just found basically the same question on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/18h0u9v/smerge_keep_lower_for_entire_file/, although I've not figured out how the solution there works. It uses the 'k' key with Magit.

Also, it seems it could be done from the "Magit mini-buffer"?
Not sure how though.
https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/4458

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, the following function works for me to automatically resolve all conflicts inside a file:

```lisp
(defun smerge-resolve-all-in-file-to (to-keep)
  "Resolves all conflicts inside a file in preference of TO-KEEP

TO-KEEP decides which part to keep and is one of `upper',
`lower', `base'"
  (interactive
   (list (completing-read "Keeping (upper, base, lower): "
                          '(upper base lower))))
  (let ((resolve-func
         (pcase to-keep
           ("upper" 'smerge-keep-upper)
           ("base"  'smerge-keep-base)
           ("lower" 'smerge-keep-lower)
           (_ (error "Unknown resolution argument!"))))
        (num-chars-bfore (point-max)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (ignore-errors (not (smerge-next)))
        (funcall resolve-func)))
    (when (= num-chars-bfore (point-max))
      (message "No conflicts were found"))))
```

It is interactive with autocompletion, so you can do a <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>smerge-resolve-all-file-conflicts</kbd> and it will autocomplete `upper`, `base`, `lower` args for you.

---

[I also sent it upstream](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=69220) because I often need such functional in my work, but Emacs maintainers don't want to accept it based on their claim that they never had such a need, hence people won't use it. If you want it to be in Emacs, please voice your opinion on the issue by emailing to `69220@debbugs.gnu.org`.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit surprising there wasn't already a built-in a way to do it.

Comment: Also, why not adding the keywords mine and theirs too?

Comment: @qazwsx well, smerge works with upper/lower terminology *(my guess is because these conflicts may be generated by other software such as Mercurial, which may have different terminology.)*. I can't guarantee that between git versions there is strict correlation between upper/lower and theirs/ours. Besides, "theirs/ours" is confusing, because its meaning changes between git commands, so it's not even a good terminology. Btw, I [sent the patch upstream](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=69220), but the discussion is still ongoing, apparently maintainers do not think it's useful.

Comment: The linked discussion was too long and complex for me to digest. Could I please get a summary from you -- is it that no existing feature help with my original need? It does require a new function like in your answer?

Comment: @qazwsx from what I understand, there was no such functional, and there also will not be unless I manage to convince them it's useful to people.